# Can QnAMaker auto-refresh URL Content it has injested

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I have a new QnA that I am building, I want the actual content to be maintained by my content providers on my website without having to teach them how to use QnAMaker too..

I have confirmed that injestion works fine... Is there a way to automate injestion from a URL (Content Refresh) so my content providers don't have to tell me and/or within X timeframe new Questions will be published to our bot automatically.. (I am cool with API calls if this isn't standard functionality.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no API for "Refresh Content" or automated way to refresh content. I did ask this question on [QnAMaker GitHub page](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/151) and still waiting to be answered. With the introduction of v4.0, Microsoft has removed the API for "Train". From my understanding (because currently, we need to click "Save and Train" whenever "Refresh Content" checkbox is clicked), "Train" api needs to be available in order to have the "Refresh Content" working if and when the api for "Refresh Content" is available to us. Looks like the API for "Train" will be available 2019 1st. So, finger's crossed that something on "Refresh Content" will be available to us by then.

Comment: I have an update to my comment above. There is a way to that. 

You can achieve this by making an update call against the knowledge base using the Update Knowledge Base API. You can read documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/csharp#Update) on how to do so.

When you make the call, your JSON body should be: {"add":{},"delete":{},"update":{"urls":["your URL"]}}

I also have written a blog on this : https://dhina.org/2019/01/11/faq-bot-refresh-content/

Courtesy: Microsoft (Github)